# Mapping feature and feature value from a line to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I am stuck on the following problem. I have to create a function which extracts the target label and feature (values) from a line and puts the features and corresponding value in a dictionary. The line format is as follows (target,  feature1: feature_value feature2: feature_value), so for example:

```
line = '1 0:2.0 3:4.0 123:1.0\n'
```

should return

```
({0: 2.0, 123: 1.0, 3: 4.0}, 1)
```

So for each feature I need to make everything before the ':' a dictionary key and everything after that the key value. But I don't know how. Up until this, I have the following code:

```
def parse_line(line):
    parse_dict = {}
    split_line = line.split()
    target_label = ''
    for i in split_line:
        if target_label == '':
            target_label = i
        else:
            # and now I need to map everything before ':' to a key and everything after to the key value 

    return parse_dict, int(target_label)

line = '1 0:2.0 3:4.0 123:1.0\n'
print parse_line(line)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the same function you used

```
line = '1 0:2.0 3:4.0 123:1.0\n'

def parse_line(line):
   data = line.split(" ")
   return(dict((i.split(":")) for i in data[1:]),data[0])

print parse_line(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the parsing in a one-liner:

```
target, features = '1 0:2.0 3:4.0 123:1.0\n'.split(' ', 1)
parsed = (dict((kv.split(':') for kv in features.strip().split())), target)
```

Example:

```
>>> target, features = '1 0:2.0 3:4.0 123:1.0\n'.split(' ', 1)
>>> parsed = (dict((kv.split(':') for kv in features.strip().split())), target)
>>> parsed
({'123': '1.0', '3': '4.0', '0': '2.0'}, '1')
>>>
```

Note that the dict keys and values are strings but you can make the transformation yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

You also can consider this:

```
# If the position of target doesn't matter:
>>> line = '1 0:2.0 3:4.0 123:1.0\n'
>>> result = [{i.split(':')[0] : i.split(':')[1]} if ':' in i else i for i in line.split()]
>>> print(tuple(result))
>>> ('1', {'0': '2.0'}, {'3': '4.0'}, {'123': '1.0'})

# If the position of target does matter:
>>> line = '1 0:2.0 3:4.0 123:1.0\n'
>>> result = [{i.split(':')[0] : i.split(':')[1]} if ':' in i for i in line.split()[1:]]
>>> result.append(line.split()[0])
>>> print(tuple(result))
>>> ({'0': '2.0'}, {'3': '4.0'}, {'123': '1.0'}, '1')
```